# Using Fluid.app is there a way to switch tabs periodically?

Tags: script, tabs, fluid.app

I'm using Fluid.app as a way to display content from URL for monitoring my servers and other services in my data center. I have a few tabs open in this fluid.app window to display another URL with other data.

I'd like to see if there is a way, to make fluid switch tabs every 20 seconds. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Developer of Fluid here. This AppleScript is supposed to do what you are asking, but it's causing a crash in the current version of Fluid (1.8.3). I'll look into it.

```
tell application "<Your Fluid App Name Here>"
    tell browser window 1
        repeat
            set c_ to count of tabs
            set idx_ to index of selected tab
            set idx_ to (idx_ + 1) mod (c_ + 1)
            if idx_ is 0 then set idx_ to 1
            set tab_ to (get tab idx_ of it)
            set selected tab of it to tab_
            delay 20
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```